# Combine console-based and windows-based application

Tags: windows, winapi, console-application, iostream, cout

Although I am using DirectX with a usual `WinMain` function in my application it happens that I want to create output to the console (with usual `std::cout`) if the application was started with specific parameters. Let's keep things simple: if the user calls the app with a `--help` parameter some help  (using `boost::program_options`) should be displayed; otherwise, everything should work usually by creating a window etc.

How can I write output to a console (if the application was invoked through one) even in my windows application?

---

*Background information:* The general idea is that before running my game engine I would be able to run some tools (either external ones, or included into the engine) and get their output.

---

**Current approach.** I have right now two separate applications, one launcher and the engine, however I am looking to merge them if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need is to create a console window for your WinMain GUI application, then you need to call [AllocConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. You are limited to one only per process.

Example in C ...

```
#include <stdio.h>

WinMain( ... ) {

    // parse the command line and check if --help is given

    AllocConsole(); // allocates console window for your process

    freopen("CON", "w", stdout); // redirects output to console

    printf( ... ); // test output to the console window

    FreeConsole(); // detaches your process from the console window

    // continue here

}
```

---

This will only *create* a console window on-demand, if you need to display something using a function like `printf` from within a GUI application. It does not make your application have both console and GUI subsystem. You need two .exe for that, so your current approach is the right one.